# I am/have been a fan?

Tags: phrase-usage, present-perfect, comparison

When you say you are a fan of someone, do you say "I am a fan" or "I've been a fan"?

Please see my example below:

> A: Why did you buy this CD? It's full of crappy tracks!
>
> Me: I bought it because I am a fan of this band.

Or is it more correct to say that you are a fan by using present perfect continuous?

> Me: I bought it because I've been a long-time fan of this band.

Comment: Both are valid, but they mean slightly different things. The first says that you are a fan *now*. The latter says that you're a fan now, but have also been a fan *for some time*.

Comment: What about *I am a long time fan of this band*? It refers to the present but includes the idea of being a fan "*for some time*". @Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both statements seem grammatically correct and convey the same emotion except timeline mentioned in later statement. Later statement is slightly different because you have mentioned 'a long-time fan'.

Comment: But one can say *I am a long-time fan of this band*.